# Butterknife plugin window not showing text fields properly in 4k resolution screen

Tags: android-studio, butterknife

I am trying to use Butterknife Plugin in Android Studio 2.3. Installed plugin, but when I choose Generate Butterknife Injection, the next window that appears has problem with the fields on the form and the buttons. How can I fix this?
[image]